# Import text from webpage directly into Numbers cells

Tags: numbers, iwork

In a numbers file I am using, whenever I open it I need to manually import a  specific value from a webpage.

Specifically, from [this webpage](https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=USD&To=EUR) I want to import the USD to EUR ratio. Any other similar webpages are welcome of course. :)

Any ideas on how to do it automatically?

Comment: Can't you use the built-in currency converter function?

Comment: @nohillside thanks. I was not aware of this formula!
Mods you can tag my question as answered.

Comment: Can you post a complete answer yourself below and accept it? This will help other users to benefit in the future.

Answer (score 1):

After @nohillside's reply, apparently there is the built-in CURRENCY function in Numbers that can do exactly what I was describing in my question.